# Jquery UI draggable function code

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I need jQuery UI for my static page which will not be online, so I can't directly add jQuery UI via a CDN. I need only the Draggable functionality from jQuery UI, so is there any option to add only jQuery UI's draggable function in my static page?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: How are you serving your static page?  is it an .html file on your local drive? or served via a server (eg IIS)?

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use a CDN, you can always serve your files from the same place you serve your 'static' page.

Many intranets work this way so they don't make internet requests.

- Open the jquery-ui download page:  http://jqueryui.com/download/
- Select the components you want, click download
- Extract the .zip file to the same location as your 'static page'
- Update your static page to include the .js and .css files from the same folder (or sub folder if you like to be tidy)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is possible. Go to https://jqueryui.com/download/ and select just the components you need to use, in this case the 'draggable' option under 'interactions'.

Then click the download button, unzip the contents, and include the files in the same directory as the webpage you are serving. Include the JS and CSS files in the HTML document in the same way as you would usually.

Answer (score 0):

In case you can't, or don't want to, download only the part of the library you use, you should check Closure Compiler from Google : https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/?hl=en

You can 'compile' multiple files with Closure Compiler.

With ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS, it removes 'dead' code, which means code that you don't use, thus if you can create one big file containing all your libraries code and your own code (by using Browserify for example), you can then use Closure Compiler to reduce drastically the size of that 'build' file.

Then all you need to do is include the 'build' file in your page. 
It's especially useful for libraries like jQuery when you only use a few of its functions.

You should be careful though to use ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS because it 'optmizes' your code by modifying it. So you should read the documentation thoughtfully.